# Single kafka pod keeps restarting

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

### Problem

Only one, single pod is failing on k8 node. Readiness and Liveness probes are indicating long resposne time, despite fact, that port is open and traffic between nodes is flowing.
Termination error code is 137.

It's up immediately after killing, however port 9092 is not opened yet, and whole recreation process of bringing app up is taking about 30 minutes.

### General environment config

We have k8 cluster consists of 6 nodes (2 nodes per each of 3 racks and racks are kept in different DC). Our kafka is deployed with helm in use, and each of its nodes is deployed on different host, due to affinity/anti-affinity.

### Kafka config

```
 - log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0
 - offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
 - log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807
 - controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
 - principal.builder.class=null
 - log.flush.interval.ms=null
 - min.insync.replicas=1
 - num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
 - sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
 - fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000
 - replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
 - message.max.bytes=1048588
 - max.connection.creation.rate=2147483647
 - connections.max.reauth.ms=0
 - log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000
 - zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=null
 - quota.window.num=11
 - zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-service.kafka-shared-cluster.svc.cluster.local:2181/kafka
 - authorizer.class.name=
 - password.encoder.secret=null
 - num.replica.fetchers=1
 - alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds=1
 - log.roll.jitter.hours=0
 - password.encoder.old.secret=null
 - log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000
 - queued.max.requests=500
 - log.cleaner.threads=1
 - sasl.kerberos.service.name=null
 - socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
 - log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime
 - connections.max.idle.ms=600000
 - zookeeper.set.acl=false
 - delegation.token.expiry.time.ms=86400000
 - session.timeout.ms=null
 - max.connections=2147483647
 - transaction.state.log.num.partitions=50
 - listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
 - log.retention.hours=168
 - client.quota.callback.class=null
 - delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1
 - log.roll.ms=null
 - replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
 - replication.quota.window.size.seconds=1
 - sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor=0.8
 - zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
 - metrics.recording.level=INFO
 - password.encoder.cipher.algorithm=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
 - replica.selector.class=null
 - max.connections.per.ip=2147483647
 - background.threads=10
 - quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807
 - request.timeout.ms=30000
 - log.message.format.version=2.8-IV1
 - sasl.login.class=null
 - log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs
 - log.segment.bytes=1073741824
 - replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760
 - group.max.session.timeout.ms=1800000
 - port=9092
 - log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000
 - log.retention.minutes=null
 - log.dirs=/kafka
 - controlled.shutdown.enable=true
 - socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms=30000
 - log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807
 - password.encoder.key.length=128
 - sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds=60
 - transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms=10000
 - sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=/usr/bin/kinit
 - log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308
 - auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
 - leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
 - log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5
 - replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
 - num.network.threads=3
 - sasl.client.callback.handler.class=null
 - metrics.num.samples=2
 - socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
 - password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm=null
 - socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
 - replica.fetch.min.bytes=1
 - broker.rack=null
 - unclean.leader.election.enable=false
 - offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
 - producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000
 - metrics.sample.window.ms=30000
 - log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
 - sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter=0.05
 - leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
 - controller.quota.window.num=11
 - advertised.host.name=null
 - metric.reporters=
 - quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807
 - auto.create.topics.enable=false
 - replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
 - replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
 - password.encoder.iterations=4096
 - default.replication.factor=1
 - sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules=DEFAULT
 - log.preallocate=false
 - transactional.id.expiration.ms=604800000
 - control.plane.listener.name=null
 - transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
 - num.io.threads=8
 - sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds=300
 - offsets.commit.required.acks=-1
 - connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms=100
 - delete.topic.enable=true
 - quota.window.size.seconds=1
 - offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000
 - log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms=9223372036854775807
 - zookeeper.ssl.enabled.protocols=null
 - log.retention.ms=604800000
 - alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num=11
 - log.cleaner.enable=true
 - offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880
 - controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
 - offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
 - transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
 - sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter=0.05
 - zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
 - log.retention.bytes=-1
 - controller.quota.window.size.seconds=1
 - sasl.jaas.config=null
 - sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin=60000
 - offsets.retention.minutes=10080
 - replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000
 - inter.broker.protocol.version=2.8-IV1
 - kafka.metrics.reporters=
 - num.partitions=1
 - socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms=10000
 - broker.id.generation.enable=true
 - listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
 - inter.broker.listener.name=null
 - alter.config.policy.class.name=null
 - delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms=3600000
 - log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807
 - zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests=10
 - log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
 - sasl.login.callback.handler.class=null
 - replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
 - sasl.server.callback.handler.class=null
 - log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728
 - advertised.port=null
 - log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288
 - create.topic.policy.class.name=null
 - controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
 - security.providers=null
 - log.roll.hours=168
 - log.cleanup.policy=delete
 - log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000
 - host.name=
 - log.roll.jitter.ms=null
 - transaction.state.log.segment.bytes=104857600
 - offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600
 - group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3000
 - log.index.interval.bytes=4096
 - log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000
 - ssl.truststore.location=null
 - offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
 - ssl.keystore.password=null
 - zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
 - fetch.max.bytes=57671680
 - max.poll.interval.ms=null
 - compression.type=producer
 - max.connections.per.ip.overrides=
 - sasl.login.refresh.window.factor=0.8
 - kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs=10
 - max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots=1000
 - delegation.token.master.key=null
 - reserved.broker.max.id=1000
 - transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms=3600000
 - log.message.downconversion.enable=true
 - transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size=5242880
 - sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
 - num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads=null
 - group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000
 - log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9
 - transaction.max.timeout.ms=900000
 - group.max.size=2147483647
 - delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms=604800000
 - broker.id=0
 - offsets.topic.compression.codec=0
 - zookeeper.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
 - replication.quota.window.num=11
 - advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka-0.kafka.kafka-shared-cluster.svc.cluster.local:9094
 - queued.max.request.bytes=-1
```

### What have been verified

- RAID  I/O - no spikes before reboot
- Zookeeper no logs indicating any connection problem
- Ping - response time is raising periodically
- Kafka logging level set to DEBUG - java.io.EOFException what is just DEBUG log, not WARNING or ERROR
- K8 node logs - nothing significant beside readiness and liveness probes

### Pods config

```
Containers:
  kafka:
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    Ports:          9092/TCP, 9094/TCP, 9999/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 10 Feb 2022 16:36:48 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Tue, 08 Feb 2022 21:12:26 +0100
      Finished:     Thu, 10 Feb 2022 16:36:36 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  76
    Limits:
      cpu:     24
      memory:  64Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      1
      memory:   2Gi
    Liveness:   tcp-socket :9092 delay=3600s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  tcp-socket :9092 delay=5s timeout=6s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE:                 false
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER:                        yes
      BROKER_ID_COMMAND:                               hostname | awk -F'-' '{print $$NF}'
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND:                                hostname -f
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:                      PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS:                                 PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:                         zookeeper-service.kafka-shared-cluster.svc.cluster.local:2181/kafka
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:            PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS:                          604800000
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS:                                  /kafka
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS:                        10000
      KAFKA_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS:                      60000
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS:          3000
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS:
```

### run command properties

```
-Xmx1G -Xms1G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/opt/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
```

### Java heap size in bytes

- uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
- uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
- uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 1073741824                          {product}
- uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
- uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 17179869184                         {product}

### Question

do you have any ideas why only this particular pod is failing, and any suggestion for further steps?

### -- EDIT --

```
Containers:
  kafka:
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    Ports:          9092/TCP, 9094/TCP, 9999/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 08 Mar 2022 17:50:11 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Tue, 08 Mar 2022 16:35:38 +0100
      Finished:     Tue, 08 Mar 2022 17:49:51 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     24
      memory:  64Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      1
      memory:   2Gi
    Liveness:   tcp-socket :9092 delay=3600s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  tcp-socket :9092 delay=5s timeout=6s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE:                 false
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER:                        yes
      BROKER_ID_COMMAND:                               hostname | awk -F'-' '{print $$NF}'
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND:                                hostname -f
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:                      PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS:                                 PLAINTEXT://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:                         zookeeper-service.kafka-shared-cluster.svc.cluster.local:2181/kafka
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:            PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS:                          604800000
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS:                                  /kafka
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS:                        10000
      KAFKA_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS:                      60000
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS:          3000
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR:          3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR:  3
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS:                                 -Xmx6G -Xms6G
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR:                3
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS:                       2
      KAFKA_REPLICA_LAG_TIME_MAX_MS:                   80000
      KAFKA_NUM_RECOVERY_THREADS_PER_DATA_DIR:         6
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kafka-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  kafka-data-kafka-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  jolokia-agent:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      jolokia-agent
    Optional:  false
Volumes:
  kafka-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  kafka-data-kafka-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  jolokia-agent:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      jolokia-agent
    Optional:  false
  default-token-d57jd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-d57jd
    Optional:    false
```

### PVC

```
Name:          kafka-data-kafka-0
Namespace:     kafka-shared-cluster
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-1d23ba70-cb15-43c3-91b1-4febc8fd9896
Labels:        app=kafka
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: rancher.io/local-path
               volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: xxx
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       kafka-0
Events:        <none>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an operator like Strimzi for maintaining Kafka health, not just installing Kafka with Helm. Most importantly, it's not clear how much heap space you've given the broker or any other resource limits your pods have

Comment: You really should lower the 64G container limit to 8G, max. Then you should increase the `-Xmx` to 6G

Comment: More specifically, exit code 137 is OOM-Killed, so you need to fix your memory problems.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will upgrade the chart and redeploy, but it's production so it may take a while. I will come back with update once it's done. thanks :)

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Reconfigured version is up and running for about 20h but Liveness and Readiness probes are keep failing on single pod :/

Comment: Is the exit code 137? Have you tried yet using the Strimzi operator?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes it's still 137 and no I haven't tried it but i'm getting familiar with documentation. is it worth to use it on already deployed cluster? do you think it can optimize our deployment? (i'm totaly new regarding to strimzi)

Comment: @OneCricketeer what i've observed is veeery log boot time of kafka. it takes even up to 30 minutes until 9092 port is available what causes further restarts. Now we've got 17 restarts in a row.

p.s.
strimzi doesn't seem to be helpful in this use case.

Comment: 1) Please edit the question with the latest changes you've made 2) Strimzi uses different Docker images, and so the JVM might be different, so it could help with both memory allocation and GC policies 3) You'll have to look the broker startup logs to see what takes a long time.

Comment: @OneCricketeer
1) edited
2) java in use:
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux-musl-x64) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux-musl-x64) (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
3) the thing taking so long is recovering after unclean killing pod - loading snapshots etc.

Comment: The last [edit] was a month ago... And I don't see any PVC details in the post either, so its not clear where data is being loaded from

Comment: @OneCricketeer i didn't expect so quick recation ;)
it's updated now with volumes part also included

Comment: I'd suggest `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: '-Xmx8G -Xms2G'` at the most. You still shouldn't need the limit of the container so high. Otherwise, you're going to have to add `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/kafka/oom-dump"` and inspect the data manually... I don't really have any suggestions for a fix other than to change the base Java version and/or the GC settings

Comment: @OneCricketeer
i've just implemented suggested configs into failing cluster. Will provide updates once failure occurs. Many thanks for your time and shared knowledge :)

Comment: @OneCricketeer above given config of heap mitigated consequences (oom), however readiness adn liveness probes are still failing. thanks once more :)

Comment: 1) Add in `0.0.0.0` to `KAFKA_LISTENERS` along with the ports 2) Should your checks use port 9094 since that's how other services will connect to it?